# Design database where each field needs to have a checkbox

Tags: database-design

I got into a problem designing a database where I have a table, where every field needs to be validated by a human.

for example:

- name
- number
- ID card number

Each one of these fields need to be validated (kind of a checkbox).

which one is the correct approach here? have boolean fields in the same tablet or a different table with each field as boolean?

Comment: For something to be considered "correct" (or not), it has to have some criteria of correctness. What are your criteria?

Comment: "have boolean fields in the same tablet or a different table with each field as boolean?" This also depend a lot on how the data will be used later, and what kind of queries you will have. Also depends if your set of attributes is fixed or may change in the future.

Comment: Do you validate all attributes for a row once, or can name be verified whilst number is not?

Comment: @Lennart some fields could not be verified at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data has to be persisted between collection and verification, and each value can be accepted or rejected individually then there has to be a `_verified` column to match each `_value` column.

These verification columns are information about the thing to which they refer as much as the name and ID are so belong in the same *logical* entity type. Whether they go in the same *physical* table is a separate matter. If split this would be considered a vertical partitioning of the logical entity. There are [good reasons](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125222/36809) to do that and good reasons not to.

If split the design and queries are more complicated. Likely response time will be fractionally better, though, since each table will be narrower. Both these can be swamped or mitigated by many other implementation details such as views or covering indexes.

Generally I'd keep a single table until proven otherwise.